# SSR with React.js (create-react-app, react-router v4, redux and sagas)

Tags: reactjs, redux, create-react-app, redux-saga, server-side-rendering

I successfully configured client and server. I can generate `html` with preloaded data but I have a problem with general concept.
At this point I need to find a way to call server to do the job when user goes to some route.
When and how I should do that? Inside `componentWillMount` ?
Component: `<Route path="/wall" component={Wall}/>`

```
class Wall extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
   if (csr){
    const { pathname, search } = this.props.location;
    //to use Promise? something like that? it should trigger server to prepare html
    return fetch(`'${servername}/${pathname}${search}'`);        
   } 
   if (ssr){
    {{fetch data and prepare index.html}}
   }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     {{code}}
  }
  render() {
    return (...)
  }
  ...
```

`General idea: user goes to /wall => client sends request to server to render it => server renders it and puts html into index.html => server responds to client with status 200 => client shows the page => updates are handled by client`
I might be wrong. Please correct me if I am. I will be grateful for any help or any other solution.

Edit:
I want to use SSR only for first load. Later CSR would take care of rest.

Comment: I think you did not understand the main concept of React itself, or is it just my impression. What is the whole point in using libs like React? The point is rendering interface faster because you request small pieces of data from server not the whole pages, otherwise just use normal html and backend server behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a custom function which fetches the data and returns a promise so that you can start the rendering after the data fetching is done and then send the rendered HTML to the client. [Here](https://blog.tableflip.io/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/) is a basic idea for that

But usually building a custom solution for SSR react app can be quite painful. I would suggest using [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) (I am using it. It's awesome) or [AfterJS](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js).

Unfortunately, NextJS doesn't support React Router 4. It has it's own routing mechanism which works fine. But if you are a fan of react router 4 or the ideology of react router 4, you can go for AfterJS

Comment: I think [AfterJS](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/after.js) is great solution for me. I will try to integrate it with redux store.  Thank you.
P.s. Originally I was a fan of react-router v3 but later I read docs for v4 and you know it all makes sense when you give it a try.

Comment: Yes definitely. I totally agree on the react router 4 thought. NextJS will soon either adopt RR4 or the RR4's ideology.

Comment: And it does not feel like v4 more like new module. They could just call it react-router-new or react-router-switch ;)

Answer (score 0):

Usually server side rendering used just for the first render. On following route changes the app works the same as single page application (i.e. calls some api, save it in some state and render it). In this case calling server to render html would not work.

Another option you can use for now, as you call server to render html, it's just use plain html links, not react-router ones, which would basically do what you described (call the server, get the html and render it)